# dapr exit immediately after running

Tags: fastapi, dapr

I am developing an RESTful API with FastAPI (python framework) and I have another service that will invoke a method (writing to a db e.g) from this API. So I wanted to implement the dapr service to service invocation. the problem is if i dapr run --api-id ... my FastAPI application on dapr cli, it runs immediately and then exit successfully without holding. How can i solve this please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGZEk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I set the dapr port to 8000 where fastapi is running and added sleep at the end of the function (while loop would be better) and service is getting invoked successfully.